# Python can't decode website UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, decode, urllib

I'm having problem using decode in python, I'm trying to fetch an IMDB website (example address: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2216240/):

```
req = urllib.request.Request(address)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
page = response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
with open('film.html', 'w') as f:
    print(page, file=f)
```

I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe6' in position 4132: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explicitly specify `utf-8` file encoding:

```
with open('film.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(page, file=f)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! By the way, it has to be encoding='utf-8', as third expected argument is otherwise buffering.

Comment: @user2837976 Note that this works only in python3. In python2 the built-in `open` does *not* have an `encoding` argument. However you can use `io.open` in this case (in python3 `open` is a synonym for `io.open`...)

Answer (score 0):

Did already use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library ?

Anyway, it made [simpler](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
#samplerequest.py
import requests

address = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2216240/"
req = requests.get(address)

print req.text
print req.encoding
```